# How to start Activity after Intent_Send (Email) is resolved

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I have an activity (B) that does a 'Intent.ACTION_SEND' to send a email with a image attached.

It works perfect, but when the email is sended, it returns to B, as is supossed to be. But I want to "jump" to activity A.

Usually I manage it with startActivityForResult --> onActivityResult. But in this case I can't do because my startActivity has a chooser (saw examples at google dev pages):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, toSender);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subjectText);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");

emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send the email in:"));
```

So my question is how can I manage to jump to other activity after the email has been send?

Comment: might be an option to wrap your functionality into a fragment, and display another fragment once you come back, because this way you should be able to use startActivityForResult. I havent tried this, but from the top of my head that should work.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android) answers your question, what you're looking for is

```
startActivityForResult
```